# Entity Framework 6 ToString(), formatting (DateTime format), query intercept

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, mapping

I`m not found correct way to search with linq2sql in DateTime (DateTime?) fields.

```cs
db.Items.Where(x => x.DateTime1.ToString().Contains("2014.08"))
```

Not work, because in linq2sql create **CAST([XXXX.DateTime1] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = '04 Aug 2014' NOT 2014.08**

I try use custom function mapping, but no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use the Year and Month property? You should be able to convert the string input into Year and Month number. Then you do something like:

```
db.Items.Where(x => 
   x.DateTime1.Value.Year == 2014 
   && x.DateTime1.Value.Month == 8)
```

It will simply be converted to:

```
WHERE (2014 = (DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[Date]))) 
AND     (8 = (DATEPART (month, [Extent1].[Date])))
```

## update

You can use [**`SqlFunctions.DatePart`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [**`DbFunctions.Right`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.right%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) to produce following format `yyyy.mm.dd`.

```
db.Items.Where(x => 
    (SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", x.DateTime) + "."
    + DbFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", x.DateTime1), 2) + "."
    + DbFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", x.DateTime1), 2))
    .Contains("2014.08"));
```

Comment: User type string "2014.08" or "08.08" or "14.08", etc. I need search this in datetime fields.

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov, I updated my answer. It should produce the format you wanted. You can use this, just in case you want to prevent using interceptor because it's applied globally.

Comment: There are problem. User filter is "12.12" it`s may be "2012.12.01" or may be "2010.12.12". Or user filter is "12" it`s any 12 in any datatime.

Comment: Hmm that should work, I tried with your sample `2012.12.01` and `2012.12.12`, and the filters are `12.12` and `12`, and both of the datetimes match both filters, because in the database those will be converted to `2012.12.01` and `2012.12.12` and `Contains` will do string filter

Comment: Thanks, you way is fine. But I can`t crete this query with Expression (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290720/conversion-in-linq-and-entityframework-expressions-type-without-expression-conv)

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov, the `DatePart` accepts nullable parameter, and nullable can accept non nullable

Answer (score 0):

1. Function in MS SQL

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ToString](@P sql_variant)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (sql_variant_property(@P, 'BaseType') = 'datetime')
        RETURN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @P, 102) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), @P, 108);

RETURN CAST(@P as NVARCHAR(max));
END
```

1. Create sql execution Interceptor

```C#
public class DbCommandInterceptor  : IDbCommandInterceptor 
{
    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command.CommandText.IndexOf("CAST") != -1)
        {
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("CAST(", "dbo.ToString(");
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("] AS nvarchar(max))", "])");

        }
    }
```

}

1. Add Interceptor to DbContext

```C#
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB(): base(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EFTest")
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new DbCommandInterceptor ());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good as sample for study but it can't be recommended: replace each CAST( with dbo.ToString( - generally would not work since EF use CAST( by its own initiative also...